# How to do operations in ListView items and to pass that data to next activity in android?

Tags: java, android

I tried using `getItem()` method and in `getView()` method, problem not solved. How to do it in each item list view and to pass that specific item data to another activity. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNP3W.jpg]

Comment: Show us the code you have, how are we supposed to guess what you have already done ?

Comment: post some piece of your code so someone can help

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

#### In XML:

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/lv"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

#### In Java:

First `findViewById`:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
```

Then make a String list and use `ArrayAdapter` for static data if you are using dynamic data then make `CustomAdapter`:

```
String[] abc = new String[] {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};

List<String> abc_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(abc));

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, abc_list);

lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Now for select an item for a particular list item use `setOnItemClickListener`:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedItem =(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

        // For next Activity use Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, SendDataActivityName.class);
        intent.putExtra("pass_data_id_name", selectedItem);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

For basic things or dynamic data use these links:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1023525/Dynamic-ListView-with-Custom-Adapter-in-Android
- http://sampleprogramz.com/android/listview.php
- https://www.developerfusion.com/article/145373/android-listviews-with-dynamic-data/
- http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-items-to-listview-in-android/
- https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listviewarrayadapter-and.html
- https://www.android-examples.com/create-listview-in-android-programmatically/
- https://www.android-examples.com/add-item-in-listview-in-android-programmatically/
- https://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to other activities:

```
intent.putExtra("myList",myList);
```

To recieve data from current activity:

```
ArrayList<E> myList =(ArrayList<E>)getIntent.getSerializableExtra("myList);
```